# Filter anomalous and complex datasets

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, filter

I have a question about how to filter and select anomalous datasets from a large df. For example, I have a df:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = {"code": ['a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'd', 'd'],
"number": [7, 5, 2, 4, 6, 9, 6, 2, 8, 2]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data=data)

  code  number
0    a       7
1    a       5
2    a       2
3    b       4
4    b       6
5    c       9
6    c       6
7    c       2
8    d       8
9    d       2
```

In this df, most of data follow a rule that in a same 'code' group, a larger number appears in the beginning. For example, in 'a' group, its values in dataframe follows: 7>5>2; in 'c' group, its value follows: 9>6>2, same pattern in 'd' group 8 > 2. But only not in 'b' group as a smaller value 4 arranges before than 6. So I wish to filter the anomalous subset b only and have an output like:

```
  code  number
0    b       4
1    b       6
```

Would anyone have any ideas? Much appreciate for help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can do `filter` then with `diff`

```
df.groupby('code').filter(lambda x : (x.number.diff()>0).any())                        
  code  number
3    b       4
4    b       6
```

Comment: A great thanks @YOKEN_S, your code is more pythonic

Comment: @Alicejinx yw:-) happy coding

Comment: Hi @YOBEN_S, I reviewed your code again, it is perfect. But I am bit confused why is the any() function in the end, and what is that for?  Forgive my ignorance as your code is too good to learn for me. Great thanks.

Comment: @Alicejinx that will return True if any diff is great than the 0 for that group ~

Answer (score 1):

```
print( df[df.code.isin(df[df.groupby('code')['number'].transform(lambda x: x - x.shift()) > 0].code)] )
```

Prints:

```
  code  number
3    b       4
4    b       6
```

Comment: thank you @Andrej Kesely, your answer is too good. Just wondering what is the default parameter or period for shift() function?

Comment: @Alicejinx According to the [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.shift.html) is `1`. One position down is the default

Answer (score 1):

```
df[df.groupby('code')['number'].apply(lambda x: (x.sub(x.shift(-1).fillna(0))<0)|((x.shift(1).sub(x).fillna(0))<0))]

   code  number
3    b       4
4    b       6
```